# How to do this hide all rows except one row in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to hide All rows except current (clicked Row) using jQuery?

I want to hide all rows when i click the particular row except current one row.

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        idValue++;

        <tr class="tableRow" id="@idValue">
            <td class="master"  id="@item.Batch_Seq">
                <a href= "#" >@(item.Batch_Name)></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @(item.Present)
            </td>
            <td>
                @(item.Absent)
            </td>
            <td>
                @(item.HalfDay)
            </td>
            <td>
                @(item.Batch_count)
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

I tried like this

```
$('.tableRow').hide();
$(this).closest('tr:not(.tableRow)').hide();
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 7):

You seem to want this :

```
$('.tableRow').click(function(){
     $('.tableRow').hide(); // hide all rows
     $(this).show(); // show the clicked one
});
```

Note that the user can't notice the row was hidden then shown : the screen isn't repaint until the event handler ends.

Comment: I always thought it was just faster than the screen refresh rate, hahaha

Comment: > the screen isn't repaint until the event handler ends.
Do you have source for what you're saying?

Comment: In case your script is before your table or you add the rows dynamically, then you might want to replace the first line with `$(document.body).on('click','.tableRow', function(){`.

Comment: finally i found myself

$('.tableRow').hide(); // hide all row in that table
$(this).parent().show(); // show current row
This Worked.

Answer (score 4):

Use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to select all elements with class `tableRow` except for the one that was clicked(`this`)

```
$('tr.tableRow').click(function() {
    $('tr.tableRow').not(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Traversing/not&redirect=no) to hide everything that isn't "this":

```
 $('table tr.tableRow').click(function(){
        $('table tr').not(this).hide(); // hide everything that isn't "this"
    });
```

or you can use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to hide the siblings of the clicked row

```
$('table tr').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().hide(); // hide the siblings of the clicked row
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/U7eUR/

Comment: finally i found myself

$('.tableRow').hide(); // hide all row in that table
$(this).parent().show(); // show current row
This Worked.

Comment: i tried sibilings() but i could hide only <td>. i couldn't hide whole row.

Comment: have you tried `$('table tr.tableRow').click( /* ... */)`, you have to bind the event `click()` to the row `<tr>` and not to cells `<td>`

Comment: Ok, but you could use the best answer :p